# Conditions Mutual Information and Confounding Effect

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, conditional-independence

Given that conditional mutual information (CMI) I(A,B |C) is the information shared between A, and B given C, does this consider the confounding effect -if any - that C introduces? In other words, does CMI isolate the effect of C and reveals the true relation between A, B?